# CustomPropertyEditor the right way

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

have a spring mvc web app and a form with a nested object which is a list. for the that nested object i need to do something like this

binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "originalCopies[0].subtitleLanguages", languageCollectionEditor);

i am not sure if iam on the right track should i bind the nested list or the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assiociate an editor to the end class (not the collection class).

Let's say you manage a `List<Language>`.
I would do

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Language.class, new MyLanguageEditor())
```